# WSO2IS Configuring SMS OTP

Tags: wso2, one-time-password, wso2-identity-server

I have configured WSO2 Identity Server following this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS541/Configuring+SMS+OTP).
But when i log in to my webapp I get the following error : 
Connection Refused.
I'm behind a corporate proxy. How should I configure IS server to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having issues with connecting outside from your network without a proxy, you can use the following jvm parameters during the server startup to provide the proxy configurations.

ex:

```
sh wso2server.sh -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8000
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1|10.*.*.*"
```

Comment: Thanks! You have been very helpful